# Tracking changes in column value over multiple data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, plyr

I am trying to track changes in student course enrollment across two timeframes (and two separate data frames). I have two data frames, one that lists courses that students were enrolled in on the first day of classes, and one that lists enrollment mid-semester.

I'm trying to track the percentage of students who stay in their first day classes (and thus also the percent that change courses), hopefully by both subject and course number.

Both dataframes look like this:

```
    YRTR    TECH_ID COU_ID  SUBJ    COU_NBR sub_cou    drop_date first_day
1   20173   12712    401    EXSC    1129    EXSC 1129   42608    42602
2   20173   12712    497    ENGC    1101    ENGC 1101   42608    42602
3   20173   128753   582    SOC     1104    SOC 1104    42608    42602
4   20173   110079   402    EXSC    1105    EXSC 1105   42608    42602
5   20173   110079   403    EXSC    1128    EXSC 1128   42608    42602
6   20173   129084   190    COMM    1111    COMM 1111   42608    42602
7   20173   364092   951    PHYS    1114    PHYS 1114   42608    42602
```

Essentially I'm wanting to track the list of courses each student (by tech_id) is enrolled in in df1 and how that compares to the courses that student is enrolled in in df2. I've been using dplyr to arrange things so far but am open to all options!

Comment: Please consider further specifying the question. What does 'compares to' in the second to last sentence mean? Please also supply the example data as the output of ```dput()```.

Answer (score 1):

Without further specification, there are very many answers to this question. Assuming that we are looking for the percentage of students that have dropped or changed courses between start and mid, then the following should do the trick. Since I could not copy the data, I have typed something similar.

First, the data frames are joined and the TECH_IDs associated with changes are identified.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df1 <- tibble(TECH_ID = c(12712, 12712, 128753, 110079, 110079, 129084, 364092),
              STR_COU_ID = c(401, 405, 411, 401, 405, 512, 500))

df2 <- tibble(TECH_ID = c(12712, 12712, 128753, 110079, 110079, 129084, 364092),
              MID_COU_ID = c(401, 407, 411, 402, 405, 512, 501))

change <- df1 %>%
  full_join(df2) %>%
  group_by(TECH_ID) %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(STR_COU_ID %in% MID_COU_ID, FALSE, TRUE),
         change = if_else(TRUE %in% change, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(TECH_ID, change)
```

Second, we calculate the percentage of students that have changed or dropped one or more courses (using magrittr) as follows.

```
sum(change$change) %>%
  divide_by(nrow(change)) %>%
  multiply_by(100)

# 60
```

Answer (score 0):

For the enrollment change I would join the data frames and then calculate the change, e.g.

`df1 %>% left_join(df2, by= "TECH_ID") %>% mutate(change = enrollment_mid/enrollment_start)`

Of course you can only select columns that are needed from df2 after the join, to avoid same columns in the resulting data frame:

`df1 %>%  left_join(df2 %>% select(TECH_ID,enrollment_mid), by= "TECH_ID") %>%  mutate(change = enrollment_mid/enrollment_start)`

or:

`merge(x = df1, y = df2[,c("TECH_ID","enrollment_mid")] , by = "mpg")`

then you can just do `%>%  mutate(change = enrollment_mid/enrollment_start)` as above to calculate the change